# Run Google Sheet Script Running for 1st entry only

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am currently running a google script to create a PDF from Google Form Inputs. I have moved my Form Response Sheet data to the 3rd row(image attached) (using the 2nd row for another formula). Every time I run the script ***it's creating a PDF for 1st data entry only***. Please suggest the changes I can make so that it gives the output every time i submit the form (trigger has already been set). This is the script-

```
function myFunction() {
  

}

function createPDF(){
    
    const info = {
      'Timestamp' : ['4/7/2021 16:30:41'],
      'Location Code' : ['3456'],
      'Upload Image' : ['https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mietxRRzJLiOzwU71dJSmHJp9H833nul'],
    }
 
  const pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1I7ChP1xRbl7GwnvAcXV_9JIHegvsU2PO");
  const tempFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1srcXlFgmh01e4Psw_dxM4bNgarY6tfli");
  const templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById("1xype5jUa6H8VJ4JSaV-KfccSjK5w6e-hmoI1k6MXSOc");

  const newTempFile = templateDoc.makeCopy(tempFolder);
  const openDoc =  DocumentApp.openById(newTempFile.getId());
  const body = openDoc.getBody();
  body.replaceText("{Location Code}",info['Location Code'][0]);
  body.replaceText(" {Timestamp}",info['Timestamp'][0]);
  body.replaceText( " {Upload Image}",info['Upload Image'][0]);
  
  openDoc.saveAndClose();

  const blobPDF = newTempFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  const pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(blobPDF).setName(info['Location Code'][0]+"-"+new Date());
  tempFolder.removeFile(newTempFile);

}
```

[image: Only highlighted cell is running on each form submit]

[image: This is the google doc I'm using for pdf creation]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is not reading data from the spreadsheet, it's using the data from the following code lines:

```
 const info = {
      'Timestamp' : ['4/7/2021 16:30:41'],
      'Location Code' : ['3456'],
      'Upload Image' : ['https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mietxRRzJLiOzwU71dJSmHJp9H833nul'],
    }
```

First you have to read the data from the spreadsheet.

```
const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActivespreadsheet();
const sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Form responses 1');
const range = sheet.getRange(3,1,1,4);
const values = range.getValues();
```

Then you have to replace the values of the arrays assigned to `info` object by the corresponding values of your spreadsheet. I.E.:

```
info['Timestamp'][0] = values[0][0];
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working perfectly well now.